# To change the default file download format in SharePoint 2013 in Document Library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint-2013

In Sharepoint 2013, how to restrict the download of a document from the document library and can we change the document download format from default format to a customized download format.
Any suggestion will be helpful.
Thanks in Adv